# Pyodbc MS SQL Server - Chinese turns into gibberish

Tags: sql-server, pyodbc

I'm trying to insert Chinese characters into an MS SQL Server database using pyodbc.
Running the following query in SSMS yields the expected:

```
INSERT INTO TestTable (testvalue) VALUES (N'面包');
SELECT * FROM TestTable;
```

```
testvalue
面包
```

However, attempting the same thing with pyodbc:

```
testvalue
é¢åŒ…
```

What am I doing wrong? Here is my pyodbc code:

```
connection = pyodbc.connect(
    f'Driver={{SQL Server}};CHARSET=UTF8;Server={SERVER};Database=Test;Trusted_Connection=yes'
)
connection.setencoding(encoding='utf-8')
connection.setdecoding(pyodbc.SQL_CHAR, encoding='utf-8')
connection.setdecoding(pyodbc.SQL_WCHAR, encoding='utf-8')
cursor = connection.cursor()
cursor.execute(
    '''
    INSERT INTO TestTable (testvalue) VALUES (N\'面包\');
    '''
)
connection.commit()
```

`testvalue` is defined as nvarchar(50).
I'm using python 3.8.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First things first, use parameterized queries.

Next, as per the [pyodbc Unicode page](https://github.com/mkleehammer/pyodbc/wiki/Unicode):

> **Microsoft SQL Server**
>
> SQL Server's recent drivers match the specification, so no configuration is necessary. Using the pyodbc defaults is recommended.

The following is all you need to insert Unicode characters into SQL Server tables with nvarchar columns:

```py
import pyodbc
connection = pyodbc.connect('Driver={ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server};Server=(local);Database=StackOverflow;Trusted_Connection=yes;')
cursor = connection.cursor()
cursor.execute('INSERT dbo.TestTable (TestValue) values (?);', ('面包'))
connection.commit()
```

In Python 2.x you would have needed to use a string literal with the `u` (Unicode) prefix, `u'面包'`, but this is not necessary in Python 3.x. As per [How Python does Unicode](https://www.b-list.org/weblog/2017/sep/05/how-python-does-unicode/):

> In Python 3, there is one and only one string type. Its name is str and it’s Unicode.

The above code has been tested to work with Python 3.6.8 and pyodbc-4.0.30 against SQL Server 2017.

Comment: Switching the driver did the trick for me. Thanks! Regarding parameterized queries, I understand this is best practice, but I want to log the queries I execute with 'logging' and it seems pyodbc does not have built-in support for this.